# Regex to minify inline JS

Tags: javascript, php, regex, minify

Using `ob_start` (PHP) I minify my HTML with a regex I copied from StackOverflow I believe:

```
$regex = '%# Collapse whitespace everywhere but in blacklisted elements.
    (?>             # Match all whitespans other than single space.
      [^\S ]\s*     # Either one [\t\r\n\f\v] and zero or more ws,
    | \s{2,}        # or two or more consecutive-any-whitespace.
    ) # Note: The remaining regex consumes no text at all...
    (?=             # Ensure we are not in a blacklist tag.
      [^<]*+        # Either zero or more non-"<" {normal*}
      (?:           # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct
        <           # or a < starting a non-blacklist tag.
        (?!/?(?:textarea|pre|script)\b)
        [^<]*+      # more non-"<" {normal*}
      )*+           # Finish "unrolling-the-loop"
      (?:           # Begin alternation group.
        <           # Either a blacklist start tag.
        (?>textarea|pre|script)\b
      | \z          # or end of file.
      )             # End alternation group.
    )  # If we made it here, we are not in a blacklist tag.
    %Six';
$text = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $text);
```

This works great, except I want to remove some whitespace from inline JS I have in the HTML files. It doesn't have to be state-of-the-art, just some basic minifying for JS. How would I go about writing a regex for that?

I tried with lookahead and lookbehind, but the lookbehind must be of fixed length, so that caused some trouble. I can hardly grasp the regex above too...

Does someone have a basic example how I would match within script tags the unneccessary whitespaces?

Comment: Do you want to indiscriminately remove whitespace from JS code?

Comment: This regex `(?>[^\S ]\s*|\s{2,})` segment is disturbing because it is identical to find: `\s+` and replace: `' '`, since the only thing it won't match is a single space, which is what it is being replaced by.

Comment: @morten.c that question hasn't really been answered. @sln no, it should remain valid JS, and both regex pieces are not identical but I believe `\s+` is better indeed.